# Oracle | Find All parent recursively and return results in comma seperated

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy, recursive-query, oracle19c

I have the following table in an oracle:

P_C_REL (Child , Parent ,Ownership)

| Child | Parent | Ownership |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41203134 | 10151091 | 100 |
| 10250181 | 40001104 | 30 |
| 40856701 | 40109963 | 100 |
| 10159060 | 40001104 | 100 |
| 41328372 | 10250181 | 100 |
| 40001471 | 10159060 | 100 |
| 10250181 | 40001471 | 70 |
| 10151091 | 40856701 | 100 |
| 40001104 | 10351678 | 100 |

One child can have multiple parents and each different can lead to different path till final parent.

I need output of child, RecursiveParents, Path.

Assuming 41203134 and 41328372 are my base child for sampling purpose.
I don't want to paramterize it. Child will come from different table.

Desired result #1 : get all the paths

| Child | Parents | Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41203134 | 41203134,10151091,40856701,40109963 | Path1 |
| 41328372 | 41328372,10250181,40001104,10351678 | Path1 |
| 41328372 | 41328372,10250181,40001471,10159060,40001104,10351678 | Path2 |

Desired result #2 : get the path which having highest ownership

| Child | Parents | Path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41203134 | 41203134,10151091,40856701,40109963 | Path1 |
| 41328372 | 41328372,10250181,40001471,10159060,40001104,10351678 | Path2 |

How can I do this in Oracle 19c?

This is my query:

```
WITH REL_TABLE(child, parent) AS
(
    SELECT  
        child, parent
    FROM    
        P_C_REL p 
    WHERE 
        parent NOT IN (SELECT child
                       FROM P_C_REL) 

    UNION ALL
 
    SELECT   
        p.child, a.parent
    FROM    
        REL_TABLE a 
    JOIN    
        P_C_REL p ON p.parent = a.child
)
SELECT *
FROM REL_TABLE
WHERE child IN (SELECT child FROM childTable)
```

I get this error:

> ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query

Comment: Please note this site is no code writing service or tutorial how to implement an algorithm.  Its purpose is to help people to solve a concrete issue with their code. So please show what you have tried and explain in detail what exactly doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Added the same . Missed to add it question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT child AS child,
       SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(child, ',' ), 2) || ',' || parent AS path
FROM   p_c_rel
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH child IN (41203134, 41328372)
CONNECT BY child = PRIOR parent
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE P_C_REL (Child , Parent ,Ownership) AS
SELECT 41203134, 10151091, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10250181, 40001104,  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 40856701, 40109963, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10159060, 40001104, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 41328372, 10250181, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 40001471, 10159060, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10250181, 40001471,  70 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10151091, 40856701, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 40001104, 10351678, 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CHILD | PATH |
| --- | --- |
| 41203134 | 41203134,10151091,40856701,40109963 |
| 41328372 | 41328372,10250181,40001104,10351678 |
| 41328372 | 41328372,10250181,40001471,10159060,40001104,10351678 |

Or, a recursive query:

```sql
WITH path (root, path, parent, ownership) AS (
  SELECT child, child || ',' || parent, parent, ownership
  FROM   p_c_rel
  WHERE  child IN (41203134, 41328372)
UNION ALL
  SELECT p.root, p.path || ',' || r.parent, r.parent, p.ownership + r.ownership
  FROM   path p
         INNER JOIN p_c_rel r
         ON p.parent = r.child
)
SELECT root, path, ownership
FROM   path
ORDER BY DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY root ORDER BY ownership DESC)
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Which outputs:

| ROOT | PATH | OWNERSHIP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 41203134 | 41203134,10151091,40856701,40109963 | 300 |
| 41328372 | 41328372,10250181,40001471,10159060,40001104,10351678 | 470 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3OCcz6uw)

Comment: Hi @MT0 , Its not giving the final Parent . Also Please explain the steps and best options considering the performance as well .

Comment: @sharanjain It is giving exactly the output as the desired output in the [question you initially asked](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77787075/1). If you change the question after you have got answers (commonly called bait-and-switch) then don't expect the existing answers to match the new question. (However, just use `path || ',' || parent` rather than `path`). I'm not going to answer on performance as I don't have your tables, indexes, data and the queries do different things (as per the different things you asked about); just use the each query for its particular use-case.

Comment: Hi @MT0 , Sorry the output row 1 was wrong but other row was having the correct outputs , hence i changed it .

Comment: @sharanjain Using exactly the same technique you used in the question `START WITH child NOT IN (SELECT parent FROM P_C_REL)` (or `WHERE child NOT IN ...`).

Comment: How can i remove root from the path output .

Comment: @sharanjain [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kDoUn79H)